# Trying to do a INSERT INTO in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

So I have created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
(
    CATEGORY varchar(255),
    CODE int
)
```

And I try to run the following code:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 ( CATEGORY, CODE )
VALUES ("xxxxx",1)
```

But I get the following error:

"Column xxxxx not found in TABLE1"

As far as I know, I am following the corect format. I am coding in Teradat SQL Assistant if that makes any difference

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers. Use single quotes for string literals. I.e. `INSERT INTO TABLE1 ( CATEGORY, CODE )
VALUES ('xxxxx',1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use single quotes around string literals:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 ( CATEGORY, CODE )
VALUES
    ('xxxxx', 1);
```

Based on the error message, Teradata seems to be interpreting the double quotes as a column name/alias.

There is a [Teradata community post](https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Single-vs-double-quotes/td-p/43164) about this:

> Single quotes are string delimiters.  Double quotes are used for identifiers like column & table names. But in Teradata double quoted identifiers are not case sensitive (this is a deviation from Standard SQL)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `SELECT` statement ?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 ( CATEGORY, CODE )
     SELECT 'xxxxx', 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 ( CATEGORY, CODE )
VALUES ('xxxxx', 1)
```